# Android Studio Run and Debug Button

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing a strange behavior of Android Studio. When trying to run an app and the build fails the Run button becomes disabled. I resolve the issue but the run button doesn't changes state. So, I have to restart the IDE. Is there any solution? Below are the screenshots describing my situation. My os is Ubuntu and Android Studio version is 1.1.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: what happens if you hit the sync button (left from AVD and SDK manager in your screen)?

Comment: The same result. The build is successful but the toolbar button are still grey. This happens only with the toolbar button. I can run the program normally from the top menu bar or via keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I've never experierenced this behavior, but if you update to the latest version of android studio and the issue remains, this may is worth a bug report.

Comment: I have the latest stable version. I tried also to switch to the latest canary... Maybe it is a bug.

Answer (score -1):

On line 176 is that red writing after the semi colon suppose to be there? Try removing it

Comment: Please read carefully before you post an answer. I have removed the error on line 176. See the last image.